# Send Skype msg via Android Intent using Skype URI

Tags: android, skype

I'd like to send Skype text message from my app. I found this docs about [Skype Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745882.aspx), and this docs about [how to use it on Android](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745884.aspx).

As per their example we can do:

```
Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse("skype:desired_skype_username?chat&topic=mytopic");
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);
myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

This code only open Skype within chat page with *desired_skype_username*. Is there a way to send a txt message without user interaction ?

Comment: I tried to achieve the same few months back but unfortunately, it is not possible as the API is not built by them.

Comment: What you can do is, copy the text you want to send, to the clipboard and inform the user using a toast that text has been copied to clipboard paste it and hit send button. :)